# Not able to get OAuth token for Magento Rest Client on OS X

Tags: rest, magento, oauth

I am using Magento version 1.9.1.0 and trying to use Magento Rest APIs using OAuth Integration.
I have consumer key and consumer secret. Now want to get OAuth token for Rest APIs usage.
I have followed http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html

In this , we needed oauth_signature and timestamp which we doesn't get when we create consumer on admin panel . Now how can we get OAuth token with only consumer key and consumer secret ?

Comment: Please go through the following link with details http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html

Hope you will find your answer...

Comment: I have followed this link and when i hit request for : Getting an Unauthorized Request Token, gets error of "oauth_problem=consumer_key_rejected".  What value we should use for "oauth_signature" key and how we can generate this value ?

Comment: Bhavna, I explained this in my answer. Please have a look on it and let me  know if have any issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow Inchoo blog http://inchoo.net/magento/consuming-magento-rest-zend_oauth_consumer/. Hope you will get some idea.

Answer (score 0):

The following parameters are required to oauth initiate process :

```
realm="",
 oauth_version="1.0",//oauth version
 oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",
 oauth_nonce="oklThLFvQkxNUpf",//a random unique value
 oauth_timestamp="1426745444", //current time stamp
 oauth_consumer_key="37d05fa37aea5513d4cda24c0b1f3e00",//get from admin 'key'
 oauth_signature="a183969724b3068b7b0d70e7ce9d0f09%26",//a random unique string
oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888" // your call back method
```

The initiate url will be like => http://yourdomain/oauth/initiate

I also attached two snap for your help. [image][image]

Comment: The first request is successful now but same type of issue In third step : "Getting an Access Token" error is "Signature Invalid". My parameters are : Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_nonce="oklThLFvQkxNUpf", oauth_consumer_key="996a45d4d4699effd638ae5c398fdcb0", oauth_signature="bf7b89cb715a6f66a0fad8475b1c878c", oauth_token="96d11cb4658a8aed3efbb4a35ef26760", oauth_verifier="ae0854cf7eb543117f0d6c7902162326",oauth_timestamp="1426755940"

Answer (score 0):

please check that .htaccess file rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
```

takes effect.

Check you use Apache (not nginx or other Webserver that doesn't support .htaccess)